# Network analysis, fastest path in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, network, shortest-path

I used this plugin and got results in the cost field, but I do not know in which units the cost is displayed (€, $ ...). Whether it's money or something else?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've not used that version of QGIS, but from your screen shot of the tool it appears you have set no units such as $ or £. So I would assume that cost is the length of the route? You do not describe what the data is or where it has come from, so assuming it's OSM then that will be in WGS84 and unless you have projected your data I'm guessing that it's length in decimal degrees? Have you tried clicking on the Help button, where does that take you? Seems rubbish that someone has created a tool then does not document it's output...?

Comment: That is not OSM data and this is TM projection in fact. It must be coefficient. When I increase speed that value is lower. Maybe it is time value in minutes.

Comment: You could try compare the value with Google Maps for the same points, see if it is time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution. I think this is the time spent in hours.
If the speed is 20km / h, the distance is 20km. Look at the picture that this is approximately correct.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand the notion of "cost" :
http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Cost_Distance_Analysis

In short, it's a weighted kind of distance, to reach point B from point A, depending on the route you're taking. The Shortest Path tool finds the route with the lowest cost.

Comment: Yes, but it is only one route to get point B in colored areas, what should I do with that value 0.67422? Is this value which one I should multiply with something else? Is this value some kind coefficient, time, money...